# Bike to Work Day, Week & Month

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, bike-to-work-month, bike-to-work-day

[Freiheit suggests we start planning](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/612/1835) now for Bike to Work Day, Week & Month (May 14-**18**). So let's do it!

We should do something **national**, hopefully in collaboration with a partner (Urban Velo, or some other publication to expand reach). Ideas?

My first kinda crazy **local** (NYC) thought:

Stakeout on the midpoints of the Brooklyn, Manhattan & Williamsburg bridges & hand out Stack Swag during the morning bike commute. Not only will (many of) the riders be hitting a wall at the midpoint (these bridges aren't an easy pedal for all), but they'll be just minutes away from putting their face into a computer screen.

The question: What should we give out? (Water bottles come to mind.) How can we make the item easy to grab? (Don't want to make riders dismount.) How can we make the item provocative?

This is just one idea. Lemme know if you have thoughts about this proposal or any other wild ideas to execute during May or right this very minute.

Comment: Note that Bike To Work Day is May **10** in the SF Bay area and many other areas.

Comment: @nhinkle has written us a blog post: [National Bike Month and Bike To Work Week](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2012/05/national-bike-month-and-bike-to-work-week/)

Answer (score 3):

Water bottles are great, and easy to hand out.  [LAB has an event site](http://www.bikeleague.org/programs/bikemonth/events.php) which typically lists the primary events in major metropolitan areas.  We could ask for volunteers from our members to be our 'rep' at the events.

Some addition to the banner graphic or sidebar on the site would be nice. Another possibility would be a side bar section highlighting key commuting posts, or with links to major events.

Answer (score 3):

Patch kits. With some sort of branding. Cheap, small, useful enough that it's likely to be kept. Consider giving out a tire lever or two with each patch kit.

Here's some example patch kits:
[image: 4 patch kit examples]

Lower-right is a nice little metal tin that contained a small stack of "pre-glued" patches, a piece of sandpaper and very small instructions. The tin is nice enough that I kept it and use it for other things.

Upper-right is a little plastic box that opens on one end. Sticker has a label with branding on big side, contents on one side and basic instructions on another side. Contents basically the same as the metal tin version.

The two on the left are big enough to hold a tube of glue and the kind of patches that you have to glue yourself, which I find work much better.  The lower left one is actually just a standard Park Tool patch kit with a sticker on it, which was much more visible when I first got it.

Answer (score 1):

A flyer with text about bike to work day and using bicycles.stackexchange.com to find answers to their questions. Maybe look through some beginning commuter questions and pick something to put the question title or even whole question and answer on the flyer....  I'm assuming something a little quarter-sheet (or maybe half-sheet) flyer.

Alternate version would be a little business card version. (1/10th or 1/12th of a sheet in a heavier paper)

Comment: We make a flyer, and put a 2-d barcode on it that links to a blog post: "So, you want to ride your bike to work?" (That would be a summary of many, many commuting questions we already have on the site.